# how to make easyui datagrid responsive?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, responsive-design, jquery-easyui

Is it possible to make easyui datagrid responsive?How can we create a responsive datagrid or fluid layout?

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive" ?

Comment: "responsive" means i want it to be auto re sized on resizing the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The solution given below adjusts to the div that the datagrid is loaded in.

```
$(function(){
    /**
     * Extend the datagrid functionality
     */
    $.extend($.fn.datagrid.defaults, {
          width: getMainWidth()
    });
});
/**
 * Returns the width of <div id="Main">
 * This can be used by the datagrids during initialization 
 * on the attribute: width
 * @returns
 */
 function getMainWidth(){
    return $("#Main").width();  
 }
```

At this point the datagrid is expanded to the full width of the `<div id="Main">`
Now the next thing that would be nice to have is adjustable column widths. So in order to achieve this you can define your datagrid like this

```
<table id="datagridID" style="display:none;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-options="field:'column1', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.18)">Column 1</th>
        <th data-options="field:'column2', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.16)">Column 2</th>
        <th data-options="field:'column3', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.32)">Column 3</th>
        <th data-options="field:'column4', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.05)">Column 4</th>
        <th data-options="field:'column5', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.08)">Column 5</th>
        <th data-options="field:'column6', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.05)">Column 6</th>
        <th data-options="field:'column7', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.05)">Column 7</th>
        <th data-options="field:'column8', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.11)">Column 8</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The parameters of the adjustColumnWidth function are percentages and they should all add to 100%

```
/**
 * This specifies a percentage width according to the #Main div
 * This is used during column initialization in order to set a percentage 
 * width.
 * eg:
 *   data-options="field:'docNumber', width:adjustColumnWidth(0.18)"
 *   sets a 18% width
 *    
 * @param percent
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function adjustColumnWidth(percent){  
    return getMainWidth() * percent;  
}
```

The datagrid initialization is as usual:

```
var datagrid = $("#datagridID");
datagrid.show();
datagrid.datagrid({
    url: gridDataURL
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some nice implementations for [responsive data tables](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/)

Comment: Thanks for the link but i want to make the easy ui data grid a responsive one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the easyui datagrid responsive.
But Easyui has datagrids and other components for mobile.
http://www.jeasyui.com/demo-mobile/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=metro-gray&dir=ltr&pitem=